# broken Reactivity when using defineStore of Pinia with options instead of storeSetup

Tags: typescript, vue.js, debugging, chrome-extension-manifest-v3, pinia

In a current Project I have two different type of Pinia storage definitions. I will post them in a shortened Form.

```
// First Storage Definition using storeStup

export const useStore = defineStore("storeId", () => {
  const isExpanded: Ref<boolean> = ref(false);
  
  return { isExpanded };
})
```

```
// Second Storage Definition using options
const useStore = defineStore("storeId2", {
  state: () => ({
    isExpanded: ref(false),
  }),
  getters: {
    getIsExpanded: (state) => state.isExpanded,
  },
});
```

If i now where to use both Stores using storeToRefs to extract isExpanded like this

```
const store = useStore();
const { isExpanded } = storeToRefs(store);
```

would they behave the same exact way or would they differ?

I am asking because I am writing a Chrome Extension and refactoring a Store and it seems I have done something to break the reactivity, because the second example is not reactive, while the first example is reactive and would e.g. cause a Component using v-if="isExpanded" to be rendered if isExpanded switches from false to true.

Any clues would be really helpful since I am completely lost and feel like I have tried everything

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `toRef`, you will recibe an advertising saying that you can loose the reactivity, but should works...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).